# How to send request and get response from soap in android

Tags: java, android, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am new in Android. 
I am working on webservice using soap, I am trying to match data from request and want to get response. I have implemented soap demo in android but not getting data through tag.
I am pasting soap method here.

```
POST /InflAirBook.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: airwebservice.ezeeibe.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "InFLAirBookService/InflAirGDSLCCAvail"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <InflAirGDSLCCAvail xmlns="InFLAirBookService">
      <AccountID>string</AccountID>
      <AccountPassword>string</AccountPassword>

    </InflAirGDSLCCAvail>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <InflAirGDSLCCAvailResponse xmlns="InFLAirBookService">
      <InflAirGDSLCCAvailResult>string</InflAirGDSLCCAvailResult>
    </InflAirGDSLCCAvailResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My Question is how to parse it for Android ?

Please help me how to send request and get response from it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest for Ksoap .. This is the link https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

Comment: Thank for response, But can you tell me how I can access soap body of this code, please provide some method, Actually I have implemented soap demo but not get data through tag.

Answer (score 0):

try this i should this will work :

```
public void GetData() {
    try{
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject("InFLAirBookService",
    "InflAirGDSLCCAvail");// second parameter is your method name which you want to call

    request.addProperty("AccountID", value1);//value1 contains value of AccountID

    request.addProperty("AccountPassword", value2);//value2 contains value of AccountPassword

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new    SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.dotNet = true;

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new   
    HttpTransportSE("airwebservice.ezeeibe.com/InflAirBook.asmx");


    androidHttpTransport.call("InFLAirBookService/InflAirGDSLCCAvail", 
envelope);

    SoapPrimitive objs = (SoapPrimitive) 
envelope.getResponse();//objs will have the response from webservice in string
//if SoapPrimitive does not work then write SoapObject.

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```